# How can I get the text of an HTML element with Selenium?

Tags: jquery, selenium

I'm trying to get the text of HTML elements. I can do it in the console:

```javascript
$('h2').textContent
```

But, when I'm going to do it in [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) with Selenium, I can't get to text. I'm trying with:

```javascript
WebElement Text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("$ ('h2').textContent"));
```

And...

```javascript
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('h2').textContent");
```

And it doesn’t work:

```javascript
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[label='Titular:']/following-sibling::*[1]").text
```

Comment: What is the error/ failure message you are getting?

Comment: Executing:WebElement Text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("$ ('h2').textContent"));
 The mistake is:  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: Executing WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('h2').textContent");
 the mostake is: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: $ is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Please Use

```javascript
String Text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks to comment, i tried it but don't work :( if you have another idea, please talk to me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Consider adding the explanation for the same.

Comment: Hello, you can use By.id, By.name, By.classname if you know the value for these properties of that h2 element and  you can get the text by using the .getText() method

Comment: Is [upper camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) ("`Text`") conventional in JavaScript? In any case, it may or may not mess with the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML snippet looks like below, then the following code should work.

Sample HTML snippet:

```html
<h2>Main Heading</h2>
```

#### Code

```javascript
/** Find the element **/

IWebElement h2Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...your XPath expression...));

/** Grab the text **/

String descriptionText = h2Element.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should locate the element correctly and execute .getText() on it, as suggested in previous answers.

A possible reason for not-working may be only an incorrect element location. Please be sure to uniquely identify the element by a given static property (assure it is not dynamically constructed). If this does not work, please place closest to the element HTML hierarchy part, so that we can help you.